# Timing of Purim Seudah

Tags: purim

I know that typically the Purim Seudah is held after davening mincha except on Friday when it is preferably started before midday.
I also know that some (if not all) Sephardim have two seudahs.
I seem to recall hearing or reading that there are some opinions that the Purim Seudah should be held earlier even when Purim is NOT on Friday.
Is anyone aware of what sources have this opinion and does anyone actually do this in practice or know someone who does?

Comment: how is your hebrew? I have a source sheet in Hebrew...

Answer (score 1):

The Terumas Hadshen
https://www.sefaria.org/Terumat_HaDeshen%2C_Part_I.110?lang=bi in the last sentence

> אף כי ישבתי מנהג זה מ"מ רבותי ואני אחריהם נהגינן עיקר הסעודה בשחרית
> כמדומה שכן נהגו ברינו"ס: Although I have justified this custom, still,
> my mentors customarily eat the essential ‎meal in the morning, as do
> I, and it appears that this is the practice in the Rhineland.‎

Seferia

This custom of beginning the seudah in the morning is futher brought down by the Shelah: https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Aseret_HaDibrot%2C_Megillah%2C_Ner_Mitzva.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he

> וכל מי שמקדים ומזרז ביותר לעשות הסעודה בהשכמה הוא משובח בעיני וכן כתב
> מהר"ר איסרל"ן שהוא ורבותיו נהגו בכל השנים עיקר סעודה שחרית וטעמא
> דמסתבר הוא דהא זו הסעודה היא נגד סעודת אסתר שעשתה על המלך ובודאי היתה
> הסעודה בעת שדרכן של המלכים לאכול ובסעודה זו Whoever has an early
> Seudah is praiseworthy and he quotes the above Terumas Hadshen.

The Elya Rabbah has a similar view
https://www.sefaria.org/Eliyah_Rabbah_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.695.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
The Mishna Berura here:
https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.695.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

This does not mean one should make his seudah only in the morning, but to avoid beginning at night when it is after purim. So there are those who make the Seudah in the morning.

Comment: Does that mean The Chofetz Chaim ate his Purim Seudah early in the day and not after mincha?

Comment: @Deuterononmy thank you!
@ DavefromBaltimore I would think that he would make 2 one in the morning and one in the afternoon

Comment: Of what value is a big seudah later after eating a small sandwich earlier? Are you arguing that you can have negative kavana to not discharge your obligation till later? Or that every seuda is a kiyum mitzva?

Comment: It is a segyua I would love to go through. I found in the Dor Hamlaktim the above quoted. I am not sure how the opinions tie togther

Comment: It would be helpful to non-Hebrew readers to translate key sources

Comment: @DoubleAA The question you pose is excellent. According to those that say you should have a seudah in the morning, why is that not Yotze your chiyuv seudah, meaning later there is no more din seudah?
I went through over shabbos to understand the Seguya and I have no clue!

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy Why do you think the sources you quote believe you would have two seudot? In fact the AH is explicit that there is no need for more than one seudah.